Tomcat HTTPS Redirect when IIS also Running
I have 2 apache tomcat applications that I want to redirect to HTTPS, but I also have an IIS application running on the same server which I do not want to redirect. If I place a security constraint like this
    <security-constraint>

        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Secured</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>

        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>

    </security-constraint>


into the tomcat main conf/web.xml file eveything gets redirected to https and my IIS application fails with the error
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.</string>

Tomcat is listening on ports 9080 (HTTP) and port 4433 (HTTPS). IIS is listening on port 9088 (HTTP). For some reason I do not understand, Tomcat is redirecting traffic on port 9088 to a secure channel.
My tomcat sites work as desired redirecting to the HTTPS port (in my case 4433).
If I remove the constraint, I can access my tomcat sites with HTTP and HTTPS and continue to access the IIS site with HTTP and everything I require works, but people can still access the tomcat sites with HTTP which is not what I want to allow. I want to force them to HTTPS.
Ideally, I need Tomcat to redirect only those applications on HTTP port 9080 to HTTPS port 4433 and leave everything else that is on IIS to continue using HTTP.
I have tried putting the constraint into just the tomcat applications web.xml files, removing it from conf/web.xml, but this does not redirect to HTTPS. I may be doing this incorrectly and I cannot find any examples about how to do it, site by site. All examples are for eveything.
I've also played around with the URL pattern trying things like
9080/*
/ApplicationFolder/*
but nothing seems to work. I get no redirection unless the URL pattern is /* and it has to be in the conf/web.xml file.

You can try to use failed request tracing to view detailed request process, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

I have created a work aruond. I have turned off all redirection on Tomcat because that is what is causing the issue. And then I have blocked port 9080 for incoming traffic. It is not the best solution because if users go to the HTTP URL, they do not get redirected. They simply get a non existant site and have to use the HTTPS URL, where the port 4433 is not blocked. This solves the issue for me but doesn't tell me why Tomcat redirection causes IIS to fail with a secure channel error.
